# Function: average length, partial derivatives

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, means

Let

$$
d_{a}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}d_{i},
$$

be the average length of the polyline given by vertices $(p_{1},...,p_{n})$ where
$p_{i}=[x_{i},y_{i}]$ and  $d_{i}=\left\Vert p_{i+1}-p_{i}\right\Vert _{2}$.

Let $\mathbf{x}$, (n,1) and $\mathbf{y}$, (n,1) be the column vectors,
$\mathbf{\delta}=[1,...,1]$, (1,n-1), and

$$
\mathbf{D}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
be the difference matrix. In the matrix form, the formula can be rewritten
using the Hadamard product as
$$
d_{a}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{\delta}(diag(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x})\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x}+diag(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{y})\mathbf{D}\mathbf{y})^{1/2}.
$$
Are the partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial d_{a}}{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{\delta\mathit{(2}\mathbf{D}\delta^{\mathrm{\mathit{T}}}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x}d^{\prime})},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial d_{a}}{\mathbf{y}}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{\delta\mathit{(2}\mathbf{D}\delta^{\mathrm{\mathit{T}}}\mathbf{D}yd^{\prime})},
$$
where $(\mathbf{d}^{\prime})^{T}=[1/d_{1},....,1/d_{n}]$ correct?

Thank you very much for your help.